# type parameters in signleton class Dart

Tags: dart, types, singleton

I have the following singleton class

```
class Singleton<T> {
  static final Singleton<T> _singleton = Singleton._internal();

  factory Singleton() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  Singleton._internal();
}
```

It give me the error below

```
Static members can't reference type parameters of the class.
```

How can I make _singleton instance type as T instead of dynamic?

Comment: If it's a singleton class, there will only ever be one instance of it, namely the static `_singleton` instance. Typing allows another part of the program to specify some type to be used during instantiation, but since it's a singleton class, that won't ever happen. Maybe add some more code to show how you would like to use this class with different types...

Comment: Consider whether it should be `static final Singleton<Never> _singleton = Singleton<Never>._internal();`. If not, it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, or which type `T` should stand for in the `_singleton` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Type arguments are unique to each instance of a class.

In a static context, they have no use, because  they cannot be predetermined. What should `T` be here?

Furthermore, as there is only ever one instance of the singleton, there is no need for generic typing. You can replace `T` with whatever type you need.